# Change mouse courser when mouse is passing the static text in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, text, matlab-guide

I want mouse cursor changing when mouse is on a `static text` (not clicking on it,only changing on the area of static text). I found these java cods in `undocumented-matlab`:

```
jb = javax.swing.JButton;
jb.setCursor(java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

I copied these codes in `CreareFcn` and `ButtonDownFcn` of `static text` but nothing changed and everything was as default. How can I do this and where should I put these codes in `static text`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a mouse motion listener as follows:

```
function init()
  %// Initialize the figure with a listener:
  h = figure('WindowButtonMotionFcn',@windowMotion,'Pos',[400,400,200,200]);
  %// Add a "static" text label:
  col = get(h,'color');
  lbl = uicontrol('Style','text', 'Pos',[10,160,120,20], ...
                  'Background',col, 'HorizontalAlignment','left');
  drawnow;
  setptr(gcf, 'fleur'); %// Optional, set default pointer.

function windowMotion(varargin)
    cursor_pos = get(h,'CurrentPoint');
    set(lbl,'String',sprintf('Mouse position: %d, %d',cursor_pos));
    drawnow;

    pos = get(lbl,'position'); %// This doesn't need to happen every time, 
                               %// it's here for the sake of demonstration.
    if (cursor_pos(1)>pos(1) && cursor_pos(1)<pos(1)+pos(3)) && ...
       (cursor_pos(2)>pos(2) && cursor_pos(2)<pos(2)+pos(4)) 
       setptr(gcf, 'hand'); %// Change to this cursor if pointer is inside
                            %// the element.
    else
       setptr(gcf, 'fleur'); %//otherwise (re)change to default
    end

  end

end
```

Please note that instead of an `if`, this could be a `switch-case` type of selection (in case you want your cursor to change differently for different UI elements).

This code was based on [this post on UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/inactive-control-tooltips-event-chaining). You can find some more information on mouse pointer modification in MATLAB [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-mouse-pointer-functions).

#### Edit

To create this callback automatically in GUIDE see picture below. Please note that you will need to change `lbl` to `handles.tag_of_statictxt` and `h` to your current figure's handle (that is usually returned by `gcf` or `gcbo`).
[image: How to create the callback automatically in GUIDE]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Where should I insert this code? I'm using `GUIDE`.