# Show listed images in Panel when a node is clicked in UITree Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, treeview, jtree

I am working in Matlab. I want to show Images in a given Panel one by one when user mouse click on a file name in tree list.  Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Code for tree:

```
src = strcat(pwd,'\Result\');
[mtree, container] = uitree('v0', 'Root',src,۔۔۔
'Position',[10 10 290 370],'Parent', imageListPanel2); % Parent is ignored
 set(container, 'Parent', imageListPanel2);  % fix the uitree Parent
```

Function to Display Image in panel:

```
function refreshDisplay(varargin)
    imgDisplayed = imshow(tmp,'parent',workingAx);
end %refreshDisplay
```

I just need to know how to call function refreshDisplay() from my tree. Again remember I want to call function from Tree Elements(files) not from node(sub directory).

Regards.

Comment: please specify where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: I want to implement mouse pressed key listener for tree elements. For example in my above GUI when user right click on aaa (1).jpg then it will perform some action like in my case show in right side panel.

Comment: but what is the question? There are no details about your code given here. How do code your treeview? Is the question, how to access the tree elements? or how to implement a `ButtonDownFcn` callback or ... ?

Comment: I updated my question. please check it. Hope you will got what is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that everything in the tree are nodes, both the folders and the images. You need to implement a check inside the selection callback to test whether the selected node is a folder.

Quoting [UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitree#Manipulation):

> The currently-selected node(s) can be accessed using mtree.getSelectedNodes. Node selection 
>   callbacks often require knowledge of the currently selected rows:

```
%// Tree set up
mtree = uitree(..., 'SelectionChangeFcn',@mySelectFcn);
set(mtree, 'SelectionChangeFcn',@mySelectFcn); % an alternative

%// The tree-node selection callback
function nodes = mySelectFcn(tree, value)
    selectedNodes = tree.getSelectedNodes;
    %// Use this to see which information is available about the node:
    %//   methods(selectedNodes(1),'-full')
    %// And the node array:
    %//   methods(selectedNodes,'-full')
    if ~isempty(selectedNodes) || max(selectedNodes.size)>1
       %// Obtain path from selected node; Source: link1 below
       nodePath = selectedNodes(1).getPath.cell;
       subPathStrs = cellfun(@(p) [p.getName.char,filesep],nodePath,'un',0);
       pathStr = strrep([subPathStrs{:}], [filesep,filesep],filesep);
       %// Also, don't forget a drive letter here ^ if required
        if ~isdir(pathStr) %// check that the selection isn't a directory
            %// this is where you need to call your refresh function
        end
    end
end  %// mySelectFcn
```

[link1](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-uitree-nodes#comment-16480)

---

You can get some other ideas in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229506/how-to-get-point-of-a-figure-using-callbacks-in-gui-when-the-point-is-inside-a/25231457#25231457), which shows how to implement a mouse tracking callback, in case you want the refresh to execute on a mouse-over...

Comment: Thanks for Answer sir. But something is still needed as i mention in my question i need to show or display image in panel so I need file name. Can you please guide me how to get file name which is clicked. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi there, please join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60449/25620190#) I'll try to help you out from there.

Answer (score 5):

Below is a quick but complete example. Code is commented and easy to follow:

```
function MyImageViewer
    % prepare GUI
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none', 'Name','Image Viewer');
    hPan(1) = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'Position',[0 0 0.3 1]);
    hPan(2) = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'Position',[0.3 0 0.7 1]);

    ax = axes('Parent',hPan(2), 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
    axis(ax, 'off', 'image')

    [jtree,htree] = uitree('v0', 'Parent',hFig, ...
        'Root','C:\Users\Amro\Pictures\', 'SelectionChangeFcn',@changeFcn);
    set(htree, 'Parent',hPan(1), 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
    jtree.expand(jtree.getRoot);    % expand root node

    % list of supported image extensions
    fmt = imformats;
    imgExt = lower([fmt.ext]);

    function changeFcn(~,~)
        % get selected node
        nodes = jtree.getSelectedNodes;
        if isempty(nodes), return; end
        n = nodes(1);

        % only consider a leaf node (skip folders)
        if ~n.isLeaf, return; end

        % get complete node path (absolute filename)
        p = arrayfun(@(nd) char(nd.getName), n.getPath, 'Uniform',false);
        p = strjoin(p(:).', filesep);

        % check for supported image types, and show image
        [~,~,ext] = fileparts(p);
        if any(strcmpi(ext(2:end),imgExt))
            imshow(p, 'Parent',ax)
        end
    end
end
```

[image: image_viewer]